# The process of practically salting a password and comparing later

Tags: authentication, salt

Is the following a viable method of Salting and storing the Salt that I can use in a commercial product ?

1. On user creation/register: I generate a random Salt string.
2. When the bellow code is executed I know their plain text password and username.
3. I store Salt in the database with the username linked to it to a separate table
4. string hashedPwd = hash(pwd+salt)
5. I store hashedPwd with the user's details in the normal [users] table

The bit I'm curious about:

1. User tries to login - they input their username and password
   **2. I take their username only, and look for it in the Salt table, if I find a match i get the Salt. yes/no ?**
2. string UserTryingToLoginhashedPwd = hash(pwd+Salt)
3. I then fetch the normal [users] details based on the username and compare db_pwd to UserTryingToLoginhashedPwd
4. If true normal login

Having a read at my question now, it sounds like the most logical course of actions but could use with some reassurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is generally the correct flow of storing a salt and password and authenticating a user later on.